# Can SQL Server Indexed View be served from a remote server

Tags: sql-server

Or would it even be wise to do it like this? I only ask because the front and back end will have heavy workloads.  The front end with traffic, accessing the indexed views.. the backed, application, importing huge files and normalizing them into the SQL server.

Not sure if it would be wise to put the Front end application and Backend application on the same server with the database.

Answer (score 2):

No. An indexed view must reside on the same database as the data it 'views'. See [Creating Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx):

> - The view must be created with the SCHEMABINDING option. Schema binding
>     binds the view to the schema of the underlying base tables.
> - Tables and
>     user-defined functions must be referenced by two-part names in the
>     view. One-part, three-part, and four-part names are not allowed.