# Indexed View in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can I create an index on a view which references synonyms which point to a linked server? Since the view isn't based on local tables I wasn't sure if it was possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can SQL Server Indexed View be served from a remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218657/can-sql-server-indexed-view-be-served-from-a-remote-server)

Comment: and trying if it possible or not was somehow too difficult...

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

You can't schema bind a view that references external objects and this is only one prerequisite for indexing it.

An indexed view can only reference objects within the database.

Comment: @user3154579 it would have no way of keeping the indexed view in synch with changes to data in external locations.